# Navigation after PHP form executes

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a my HTML code and PHP code in seperate documents so the HTML contains the textboxes etc and the PHP file contains the actual mySql command to write an entry to the database. I want to have it so that after the PHP code executes a pop up comes up saying "Your entry was successful" and then navigate back to the homepage or else back to the page I just came from. My HTML form is as follows

```html
 <form action = "submitEvent.php" method = "post"> 
  Event Name: <br> 
  <input type = "text" name = "eventname" > 
  <br>
  Event Type: <br> 
  <input type = "text" name = "eventtype" > 
  <br>
  <!-- need to find a way to get charityID to link the tables
  without having the user enter the charityID -->
  Charity Number: <br> 
  <input type = "text" name = "charityid" value="<?php echo $charityid;?>" > 
  <br>
  Contact Details: <br> 
  <input type = "text" name = "contactdetails" > 
  <br>
  Location: <br> 
  <input type = "text" name = "eventlocation" > 
  <br>
  Date : <br>
  <input type ="date" name ="eventdate">
  <br>
  <input type = "submit" value = "Submit"> 
</form>
```

and the submitEvent.php file is as follows:

```html
include 'conn.php';

$eventname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'eventname');
$eventtype = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'eventtype');
$charitynumber = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'charityid');
$contactdetails = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'contactdetails');
$eventlocation = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'eventlocation');
$eventdate = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'eventdate');

//Check connection 
if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
$sql = "INSERT
    INTO event (eventname, eventtype, charityid, contactdetails, location, date) VALUES ('$eventname', '$eventtype', '$charitynumber', '$contactdetails', '$eventlocation', '$eventdate')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
 
        header("location: index.php");
} else {
 echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

At the moment it just navigates back to the homepage but I would like also a notification to appear either on the homepage or before hand so that the user knows the record was created successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ajax request and jQuery

```
<form method = "post" id="event_form"> 
      Event Name: <br> 
      <input type = "text" name = "eventname" > 
      <br>
      Event Type: <br> 
      <input type = "text" name = "eventtype" > 
      <br>
      <!-- need to find a way to get charityID to link the tables
      without having the user enter the charityID -->
      Charity Number: <br> 
      <input type = "text" name = "charityid" value="<?php echo $charityid;?>" > 
      <br>
      Contact Details: <br> 
      <input type = "text" name = "contactdetails" > 
      <br>
      Location: <br> 
      <input type = "text" name = "eventlocation" > 
      <br>
      Date : <br>
      <input type ="date" name ="eventdate">
      <br>
      <input type = "submit" value = "Submit"> 
    </form> 

<script>

$(document).ready(function (){
    $("event_form").submit(function (event){
       event.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
                    data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
                    type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: 'submitEvent.php', // the file to call
                    success: function(responce) { // on success..
                        alert('Your entry was successfully processed');
                        window.location='index.php' // write the url of your page that you want to navigate to
                    }
                });
                return false; // cancel origin
    });
});

</script>

//use cdn google or microsoft
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
```

for more info go to [jquery Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/submit/#submit-eventData-handler)

Answer (score 0):

or you could save the message in a session, then  at the redirect page say

```
if(isset($_SESSION['message'])) echo $_SESSION['message']
```

don't forget to unset it when you are done